# Unable to understand this code from CodeGolf

Tags: c, argv, puts, nul

So I was losing my week-end on StackOverflow and saw [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125282/goodbye-cruel-world) in the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot).

> **Background**
>
> Hello golfers! I would like to learn all the programming languages!
>   But I kinda have a short attention span... and copying all the Hello
>   World examples gets boring... but I like fire! ^w^
>
> **Challenge**
>
> So here is the plan! I want you all to write the smallest code that
>   will compile, print Goodbye Cruel World!, and then crash. Or, as a
>   bonus twist challenge, print Hello World! and crash with Goodbye Cruel
>   World!

As a student willing to understand wholly the C language, I have been very confused when stumbling upon the [C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125320) to this challenge :

```
main(){puts(puts("Goodbye Cruel World!"));}
```

> Prints the string and then tries to use the return value as a pointer
>   to another string to be printed, which causes a segmentation fault.

Thanks to `puts()` [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_puts.htm) I have found that `puts()` returns a non-negative value on success. So if I understood correctly, this is equivalent to something like :

```
puts(2);
```

How `2` is "*a pointer to another string to be printed*" ??

Later, an improvement has been added to this very same answer :

```
main(i){i=puts("Goodbye Cruel World!")/0;}
```

And this time I am totally lost. So `i` is taken as an argument from main, used to store the return value of `puts()`. Ok. But what about the `\0` ? Why use the `NUL-TERMINATOR` character there ?

If you could please lighten me up a bit, it would be very interesting for me to understand this. Also, I think the title of the question could be a bit more accurate if rephrased but I haven't been able to put in words my misunderstand.

Comment: @Downvoter a hint ?

Comment: None of this is valid C code and your compiler should complain for various reasons. If not, get a new one or change to standard C and enable recommended warnings. And we are not an explanation service for obfuscated == bad code.

Comment: `/0` means "divide by zero"

Comment: As a sidenote: the C language does not have a concept of "crashing".

Comment: Undefined behavior means your code _may_ crash; or it may do something far more sinister....

Comment: @Olaf I don't remember asking to explain the whole code, which I understood quite well. I am asking why this code is failing and what exatly happens with the `puts(2)`.

Comment: @Badda: This is apparently impossible to answer. Meditate about the meaning of _**undefined** behaviour_

Comment: @Olaf Well explaining **where** the UB happen and **why** would have been enough for me to understand and accept an answer..

Comment: @Badda: You already pointed out where UB happens. And your compiler should also do! Why do you ignore warnings?

Comment: @Olaf, the original is code golf, and the requirement there is explicitly to crash. There's going to be some bending of the rules involved, and that's not due to the person asking _this_ question.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Thanks, I can read and understand english language text. You missed the point! We are not the codegolf support site. If there is a question about some CG code, it should be asked there.

Comment: Learning/understanding C is going to be very difficult, if not impossible, if you try to do it by reading golfed code. Instead, look at some open source projects or some highly-upvoted Stack Overflow answers as examples of *good* and *correct* code.

Comment: "*But what about the `\0`?*" I see no `\0`.

Comment: Did you compile and ran or even tried to debug `main(i){i=puts("Goodbye Cruel World!")/0;}`? Doing so is the most straight forward approach to understand what is really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions cause undefined behavior.

The first solution:

```
main(){puts(puts("Goodbye Cruel World!"));}
```

evaluates `puts("Goodbye Cruel World!")`, which returns a non-negative value on success. This value is passed to `puts()`. Now, according to [§6.5.2.2 7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p7):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, **as
>   if by assignment**, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
>   the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
>   declared type.

So the code attempts to convert the value returned from the first call to `puts()`, as if by assignment, to a value of type `char *`. This is the type of the left operand in the assignment, while the type of the right operand is `int`. The left operand is a pointer type, so the right operand must be a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of a compatible type, a pointer to `void`, or a null pointer constant([§6.5.16.1 1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1)). None of these are true, so this is a constraint violation, and the compiler must issue a warning.

This is undefined behavior, in the sense that there is no behavior defined for what should occur if you run this code.

The second solution is also undefined behavior, since division by zero results in undefined behavior ([§6.5.5 5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p5)):

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the
>   first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undefined.

Undefined behavior may or may not include the "crashing" of your program.

Answer (score 3):

And to answer your second question :

```
main(i){i=puts("Goodbye Cruel World!")/0;}
```

There is a difference between `'\0'` and `/0` 
The first one is the `NUL` character but the second one is a division by zero. So this code tries to divide the result of `puts` by zero.

Answer (score 2):

The code is failing because the type of the argument to `puts()` is `const char *`, meaning "pointer to read-only `char`".

This is static, it doesn't change just because you try to pass it something else, instead the function interprets the argument value as if it was a pointer to a character (assuming the compiler even managed to compile it, which is a tough assumption here since the `int` value returned doesn't convert to `const char *`).

In general small integers like `2` are not valid as pointers on desktop/server-class systems (and not on all embedded ones, either), i.e. there is no memory available to a typical process at that address, so what often happens is that the operating system stops the process for violating its bounds. But, as has been mentioned in comments, this part is *undefined*.

Comment: The pointer passed need not be `const` (C has no concept of "read-only"). It just guarantees that `puts` does not modify the pointee. "In general small integers like 2 are not valid as pointers" - Very risky assumption. Most systems are embedded systems and on most of these lower address values _are_ valid. You better restrict this to full-size OSes like Linux, Windows, etc.